# 3D button with triangle

Tags: css, css-transforms

I try to create a 3d-ish button with a triangle edge.
[image]

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with the triangle part. The bottom layer doesn't match with the top layer.
I'm using border technique for the triangle. The bottom layer should be 4px far from the top layer.

JSFiddle at the bottom as well.

```
<a class="btn" href="#"><span>Button text here</span></a>

scss:

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    background: #EAC118;
    padding: 0 30px;
    line-height: 55px;

    span {
        display: block;

        &::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: -16px;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 27px 0 28px 16px;
            border-color: transparent transparent transparent #EAC118;
        }
    }

    &::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 4px;
        bottom: -4px;
        right: -6px;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        background: #ff0000;
    }    

    &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: -22px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 24px 0px 28px 16px;
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff0000;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/th2hqmLz/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this - I have just made the span inherit the same styles and offset it to the bottom and right by -5px and then made another arrow to line up with the outer arrow:

```css
.btn,
.shadow {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  background: #EAC118;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn::after,
.shadow:after,
.shadow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 28px 0px 28px 15px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #EAC118;
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #ff0000;
}

.shadow::after {
  border-color: white white white #ff0000;
  left: calc(100% - 3px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.shadow::before {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff0000;
  bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.shadow > span {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-top: 5px solid #ffffff;
  background: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#">
  Button text here
  <span class="shadow"><span></span></span>
</a>
```

**Example using a background image:**

```css
body {
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(http://www.eelt.org.uk/img/eso1716a.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}

.btn {
  margin:100px;;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  background: #EAC118;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #A5CAE5;
}

.btn::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 15px;
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFGSV.png) top left no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#">
  Button text here
</a>
```

Comment: All of them are good solution, and I feel I achieved the same or similar, but the problem is that the point of the triangles is not next to each other. See attached design. But maybe it's not even possible.

Comment: In your design the point of your arrows line up so it is not a proper shadow. If you want it like that then you would have to create a different shaped triangle for the background image

Comment: @levipadre see edit, bit hacky but seems to achieve what you want

Comment: Nice one @Pete. Thank you!

Comment: Also, it won't work, unfortunately, if the background is an image. I just noticed.

Comment: Ah yeah, was going to say I had to turn part of the second pointer white to hide the below pointer parts - probably best using an svg for the arrow part and just stretching it to fit the height of an after on the button

Comment: @levipadre I have added an example with a png - if you use a svg, it will be better quality in the resize

Answer (score 0):

[filter: drop-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) may simplify the job soon

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  background: #EAC118;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  filter: drop-shadow(6px 4px 0px #ff0000);
}
.btn span {
    display: block;
}
.btn span::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -16px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 27px 0 28px 16px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #EAC118;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#"><span>Button text here</span></a>
```

be aware that from now

> Chrome and Safari (WebKit-based browsers) do not support this parameter; the effect will not render if used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea with linear-gradient:

```css
:root {
  --c: yellow;
  --triangle: 
  linear-gradient(var(--c), var(--c))0 0/calc(100% - 30px) 100% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 50%, var(--c) 0) 100% 0/30px 50% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%, var(--c) 0) 100% 100%/30px 50% no-repeat
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: var(--triangle);
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--triangle);
  filter: hue-rotate(100deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  This is a 3D button
</div>
```